# C# WPF TextBox Binding Text as array[1] of Selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to bind a textbox to to an array property of a selecteditem of a DataGrid

```
<TextBox Name="txtMaxJoueur" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MinMaxJoueur[1], ElementName=dgJeux, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="130,75,10,10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

But it gives this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MinMaxJoueur' property not found on 'object' ''JeuSociete' (HashCode=7421470)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.MinMaxJoueur[1]; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='dgJeux'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtMaxJoueur'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Anyone knows how to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SelectedItem` doesn't have have property (MinMaxJoueur) that you are referring to. So check your data source that you are binding to the data grid and ensure that you have a property called MinMaxJoueur.

Answer (score 0):

As Nair suggest you must bind your `DataGrid` column to a object that have `MinMaxJoueur` property.

for example:

```
public class Test
{
   public string[] MinMaxJoueur { get; set; }
}
```

and set `DataGrid.ItemsSource`:

```
private void SetData()
{
    List<Test> tests = new List<Test>
    {
       new Test() { MinMaxJoueur = new string[] { "1", "3", "5" } },
       new Test() { MinMaxJoueur = new string[] { "2", "4", "6" } }
    };
    this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = tests;
}
```

and in xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Project1.Window1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            WindowState="Maximized">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0" Width="100" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MinMaxJoueur[1], ElementName=DataGrid, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Margin="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MinMaxJoueur" Binding="{Binding MinMaxJoueur[1]}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```